# I can't insert values ​into mongodb using docker compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm create a Docker File.

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /home/node/

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8888

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

After, create a dockercompose.yml file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api_node
    restart: always
    build: 
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node
      - /home/node/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: node server.js

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

When run docker-compose up, docker creates the containers, but I can't save schema in mongodb.
The error appears:

> MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after
> 10000ms
>
> at Timeout.
> (/home/node/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:184:20)
>
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
>
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

My server.js

```
// Constants
const PORT = 3000;

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect = ("mongodb://mongo:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const userSchema = {
  username: String,
  email: String
};

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home")
});

app.get("/register", function (req, res) {
  console.log('deu certo');
});

app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
  console.dir(req.body);
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email
  });
  console.log(newUser);
  newUser.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Deu certo');
    }
  });
});


app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

I've already made several changes, but I still don't know what's going on.

Comment: Does it work locally ?

Comment: Link the mongo service to the app service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define a `network` in the `docker-compose.yml` so that the services are in the same network and have access to each other:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api_node
    restart: always
    build: 
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node
      - /home/node/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: node server.js
    networks:
      - my-net

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - my-net

networks:
  my-net:
```